# how to check for duplicate column values in a row before updating in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

- List item

In the below table, i want to update row m3 where owner = 10000, but check before updating that this row do not have a duplicate value.
For eg: 20 should not be allowed and alert the user, 40 is allowed as it do not have any other repeated value.

[mytable]

Comment: You mean column m3?

Comment: Yes see this image for clarity,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCWms.png

Comment: please post your sample data as text

Comment: Use unique constraint for the column and when your query fails die with your error message

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try something based on this:

```
SELECT * FROM <your table> WHERE owner=<your owner value> AND <your value to ckeck> NOT IN(M1,M2,M3,M4)
```

You can use the condition directly in UPDATE too.

Comment: Thank you Very Much , That would help me move forward with my project.

Comment: Pls, next time, try to post question following Stackoverflow suggestions (see tour) (Eg. sample data, output expected, your tries, etc.)